# Looking for weekly death data by State/County/City

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, europe

I'm looking for up to date weekly death rates in first the US (ideally EU and East Asia sources would be great too) that is tracked at a city/county level (implying state level as well). Something like EuroMOMO but the actual datasets.

Answer (score 0):

[Birth, Death, and Other Vital Statistics](https://www.health.pa.gov/topics/HealthStatistics/VitalStatistics/Pages/vital-statistics.aspx)

---

[National Center for Health Statistics](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/state-and-territorial-data.htm)

---

[Michigan Mortality Statistics](https://www.mdch.state.mi.us/osr/index.asp?Id=4)